# Can I use 3v CR2032 to power multiple vibration motors?

Tags: arduino, power-supply, series, coin-cell, vibration-motor

I am planning to use a 3v Arduino pro mini with 2 coin cells (3v CR2032 each).

I also need to connect 6 flat vibration motors in series rated as follows:-
**Rated Voltage: 3v,
Rated Current: 70mA**

Can I use 2 coin cells (CR2032)?
**Each Rated:-
Nominal Voltage: 3 Volts,
Nominal Capacity: 220 mAh,
Nominal Discharge Current: 0.2 mA**

If not, please suggest how to proceed ahead, what power source should I use and how. I only have a limited housing/space so a small battery is prefarable.

Please help me its my first project.

Comment: What do you think when looking at the battery nominal current vs the motor current rating?

Comment: Maybe a CR123A will do if can compute series wont work

Comment: To get a current of 70 mA from a cell with 0.2 mA, 70/0.2 = 350 parallel cells would be needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, with a discharge current of 0.2 mA, there's no way you can power even one motor that draws up to 70 mA, let alone 6.

Look into small Lithium Ion batteries, something like [this](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13851) can produce a sustained 80 mA, which will power one of your vibration motors. It could maybe run all 6 briefly, but I would go bigger just to be safe.

For what it's worth, I would try to not run all 6 at the same time if you can get away with just doing one at a time. You also could PWM the motors so they don't draw their full complement of current if you need to limit that.

Also, if you're going for maximum power or efficiency, connecting these motors in series probably won't give you the results you want. Go parallel or separately powered.

Use a transistor of some sort to switch the power—the output pins of an Arduino won't be enough to drive them.

Comment: hey! @krs013 thanks for guiding me. Can you please elaborate on using transistor to switch the power? I just have to use the motors for short bursts. Thanks again buddy:)

Comment: [This guide from Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-arduino-lesson-13-dc-motors/transistors) is a good place to start. If you're going to power all 6 on one circuit, though, a 2N2222 won't be enough. TIP31 may be better. Also the extra diode is important; don't leave that out.

Comment: I am planning to make vibration patterns with motors similar to LED patterns. As you suggested TIP31 would be a better choice. If I try to switch ON just a single motor will that work with T1P31? Thanks for saving my ass man.  :D

Comment: My project is going to be same as blinking LED patterns but instead of LED's blinking motors will vibrate. Sorry, I am really new to this so I am asking all these questions. :(

Comment: If the motors are controlled separately you can use lighter transistors like 2N2222 or 2N3904--just look at the data sheets for how much current they can source/sink. TIP31 is higher power, so you would need it if you are connecting all the motors together. If they're separate, any of those three work. And don't worry--there's a lot to learn, but there are lots of good resources out there too.